# The CAS management webapp is Unavailable

Tags: cas, jasig

Using CAS 4.0.1 and successfully build with maven cas webapp and cas management app.

Accessing the cas-management app shows the services gui with the following error:

"The CAS management webapp is Unavailable
There was an error trying to complete your request. Please notify your support desk or try again."

Comment: I am also getting the same error in linux. When I had the CAS server in windows, i was able to get past through it, but when I moved it to Linux, I am started getting this error. Not sure what I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve my problem and I hope it might help you as well.
The reason behind this error is the security certificate was not in the VM parameter for my CAS server, namely 
`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustword"`

If the CAS server has both cas and cas-management, then it requires the client certificate of this server to be part of the VM param.
The link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore shows how to create server and client certificates.